# Issue when trying to build the APK for release on MacOS

Tags: flutter, dart, build, runtime-error, apk

Execution failed for task ':cached_video_player:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:/Users/mac/flutter_project/nack/build/cached_video_player/intermediates/merged_res/release/values/values.xml:141: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

I'm using the cached_video_player package in my Flutter project to display videos. The project was working fine with the package until I tried to build an APK for release using the command flutter build apk --release. This error occurs during the build process, and I'm unsure how to resolve it.

Reproduction Steps:

Create a new Flutter project.
Add the cached_video_player package to the pubspec.yaml file.
Use the package in a widget to display a video.
Run flutter build apk --release to generate the release APK.
Environment:

• Flutter version 3.13.4 on channel stable at /Users/mac/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 367f9ea16b (3 weeks ago), 2023-09-12 23:27:53 -0500
• Engine revision 9064459a8b
• Dart version 3.1.2
• DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/mac/flutter
• Platform android-33, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14C18
• CocoaPods version 1.12.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.74.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.6.2 21G320 darwin-x64
• Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 117.0.5938.132

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

## Packages:

```
  cached_video_player:^2.0.4
  provider: ^6.0.5

  shared_preferences: ^2.0.17
  get: ^5.0.0-beta.52
  http: ^0.13.5
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.6+1
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  intl: ^0.17.0

  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  cached_video_player: ^2.0.4

  enough_giphy_flutter: ^0.3.0
  flutter_sound: ^9.2.13
  path_provider: ^2.0.14
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0

  swipe_to: ^1.0.2
  file_picker: ^5.2.6
  video_player: ^2.7.2

  flutter_local_notifications: ^14.1.1
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.4

  firebase_auth: ^4.4.2
  cloud_firestore: ^4.5.3
  firebase_storage: ^11.1.1
  firebase_core: ^2.10.0
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.6

  firebase_admin: ^0.2.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.5.0

  cloud_functions: ^4.2.0

  pie_chart: ^5.3.2
  geocoding: ^2.1.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11
  flutter_linkify: ^5.0.0
  flutter_colorpicker: ^1.0.3
  gallery_saver: ^2.3.2
  audioplayers: ^5.2.0
  emoji_picker_flutter: ^1.6.1
  # share_plus: ^7.1.0
```

what i tried:
`flutter clean`, `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 7.5`, `./gradlew clean`, `./gradlew assembleRelease`

**Expected Behavior:**
I expected the APK to be generated successfully without any resource linking errors.